# How to add another icon in the toolbar with NavigationView

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have create an Android application using `NavigationDrawer`. When the application is created, there is one icon menu set by default, placed in the left of the toolBar. And my aim is to add another icon placed, for example, in the right of the toolbar. I have tried many tutorials by following them step by step, by I can't achieve it. Could anyone help me?

[image: Here is my wish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a menu to achieve this task. For example;

`res/menu/menu_main.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/new_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    </item>
</menu>
```

If you already have a menu then you can continue with it.

After you have created the menu, you need to inflate it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Refer this for more details about using the menu resource: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource

Comment: Thank you so much  @Amila, I have tried this, it works fine too!!

Answer (score 1):

in activity

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu)
return true
```

}

to handle clicks on menu items

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
// Handle item selection
return when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.new_game -> {
        newGame()
        true
    }
    R.id.help -> {
        showHelp()
        true
    }
    else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

}

---

in menu folder `game_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
      android:title="@string/new_game"
      android:showAsAction="always"/> // this icon will be always shown
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"// add you icon image
      android:title="@string/help"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> // this icon will be shown if there is space available 
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are Using Toolbar set as Actionbar (setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)) or Actionbar alone:**

In your Activity:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu_home, menu)
    return true
}
```

In `res -> menu` folder add a new file named `menu_home` (if menu folder does not exists make one):

Add as many items you need to `menu_home` file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_01"
        android:title="@string/my_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    ...
</menu>
```

`showAsAction="ifRoom"` makes icon available in Toolbar if there is room for it. you also have an option for `never` as it goes inside the popup menu.

---

**If you are using Toolbar only (without setting as Actionbar):**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_home"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: it works like a charm, I am using first case, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

In your menu.xml add :

```
<item
    android:title="icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:id="@+id/menuitem_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/micon"

    >
</item>
```

Then in OnCreateView: setHasOptionsMenu(true); Closing the OncreateView below write this method:

```
@Override

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.icon, menu);
    ...
}
```